# prevent duplicate enteries sql php

Tags: php, sql, duplicates

I am working on a database system and i am trying avoid duplicate entries for email and username. i have tried but it is still rejects but unable to see exactly what is being rejected. 
can someone tell explain where i am wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

 $sql="INSERT into users (username,password,email) VALUES('$username','$password','$email')";

 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('duplicate')");

 if (!$result) {
echo "Enter a different value";
 } else {
echo "Save successful.";

}
}
```

Comment: Set a UNIQUE constraint or use `mysql_num_rows()` or `COUNT()`. Plus, do not store passwords in plain text; danger.

Comment: first use select for checking the username! and then try to insert it after!

Comment: unique constraint's the only acceptable one. numrows/count is racey and can/will cause problems.

Comment: Then your query is wrong `$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('duplicate')");`, it does next to nothing. Remove that and do `$sql=mysql_query("INSERT...` then `if (!$sql) {` and looking up the functions I've given you above.

Comment: This `$sql="INSERT` will never happen, btw. Least, not as you posted it.

Comment: FRED-ii-i have updated the code above does this look right?

Comment: Remove `$count = mysql_num_rows($result);` and do `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){ echo "Exists"; exit; }`

Comment: i am getting this error when i inserted what u suggested above.. mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given  on line 70

Comment: Oh wait a minute. `mysql_num_rows()` is for SELECT, my mistake. You need to first query your DB, then do the INSERT. That would go in the `else{...}` part. Plus, do not constantly change your question. I will formulate an answer for you shortly.

Comment: Do you have a column called "Email"?

Comment: I've posted an answer for you below. Please go over it entirely and carefully.

Comment: There was an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: Again, please do not constantly update your question with new code. I have performed a rollback to the original question/code.

Comment: sorry i couldnt post it in the comment wanted you to see the code. i will make sure i dont next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only formulating this answer in order to show you the basics of checking for duplicates and inserting.

You should ultimately set a UNIQUE constraint on the given column(s) and use a conditional statement based on the error result.

Consult my **footnotes** below in regards to security.

*Sidenote #1:* You can remove `OR Username= '".$username."'` if you don't want to check if both Email and Username exist.

*Sidenote #2:* - I'm unsure whether your column names are mixed case, so you may need to do a few adjustments.

- Email or email - Password or password - Username or username

*Sidenote #2:* - Make sure that all your elements hold the name attribute and that the form is indeed using a POST method.

Query first, then if the user/email does not exist, perform the INSERT.

This, assuming you have already established a [**DB connection**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php): (consult other notes below footnotes, under *"Establishing a DB connection"*).

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users 
          where email='".$email."' 
          OR Username= '".$username."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
     echo "A record already exists."; 
     exit;
    }

else{
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT into users (email, Username, Password) 
                       VALUES ('".$email."','".$username."', '".$password."')");
}

if($insert){
    echo "Success";
    }

else{
    echo "There was an error " . mysql_error();
    }

mysql_close();

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

---

You can also replace

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

with

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

for some added security until you start using prepared statements.

---

**Footnotes:**

Concerning security.

Do not use the older `mysql_` API, nor should you be storing passwords in plain text.

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

*Establishing a DB connection:*

I.e. from the manual of [`mysql_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php):

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: i keep getting this error. There was an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: @zahid I kind of thought so. I noticed the error earlier and you may not have noticed the edit I made; I forgot a closing `)` bracket in the INSERT. Reload the answer again and recopy.

Comment: oh yea the ")" i thought it looked abit odd. thanks it add the user but the "email" is not showing in the database. it is blank

Comment: @zahid It's blank because it hasn't been included in the query. Just add it following the same method. Change `(Username, Password)` to `(email, Username, Password)` and `('".$username."', '".$password."')` to `('".$email."','".$username."', '".$password."')`

Comment: thanks for your help i have a better understanding now. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hi check your mysql table definition if email and username column have UNIQUE KEY set. Without this flag table still accept all emails and usernames.

Also try to get info if something bad happen.

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the structure of your table column of email and username to UNIQUE
then everything will be fine.
if you tried to insert duplicate data
it will not insert and mysql_query will return false

Answer (score 0):

When creating a table...

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  column_name data_type(size) constraint_name
)
```

...you can use the `UNIQUE` constraint like so:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  column_name data_type(size) UNIQUE
)
```

This constraint is case-insensitive, which means '*UsErNaMe*' and '*username*' are considered identical.

**Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) for more info about this constraint.**